# how to use grid to show the layout what image shows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Sorry I am really newbie to css grid
I have a layout has 5 areas that seems like image shows below:
[image]

How should I use grid to show this layout ??

Comment: You need to make 5 column and 6 raws I would say

Answer (score 1):

Here your grid, made with: https://grid.layoutit.com:

```css
.grid-container {
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2.5fr 4fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 0.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
}

.red {
  /* grid-row-start / grid-column-start / grid-row-end / grid-column-end */
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 5 / 2;
  background:red;

}

.purple {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  background:purple;
}

.gold {
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / 4 / 5;
  background:gold;
}

.blue {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 6 / 3; 
  background:blue;
}

.green {
  grid-area: 6 / 2 / 7 / 3;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="purple"></div>
  <div class="gold"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```